# UnRAID performance vs. bare metal performance - any tests out there?

Tags: performance, virtualization

I couldn't find any, so perhaps anybody has done some tests? Assume that both hosts are turned on, but one of them is an idle system. One would be Linux and another Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UnRAID would appear to be almost an appliance which runs [Linux](https://lime-technology.com/technology/), software RAID and [KVM](https://lime-technology.com/virtualization-host/).  There is nothing inherently bad about this, although (from the website), they seem to be [pushing something very similar to RAID5](http://lime-technology.com/forum/index.php?topic=2213) - without calling it this - and that should be triggering alarm bells as 4TB disks should not be used in this configuration if you value your data.

From a performance point of view, it will depend on your hardware, but (for KVM) the performance hit is not that significant when set up to pass raw block devices through - I believe 95%+ of native speed would be typical on modern hardware.